# Can a C++11 function return when the threads joined to it still not terminated?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory-leaks

I have a function in my code which is not the main function and uses threads. It is called thousands of times when the program is run. It looks like this

```
void my_function(vector<string> input, vector<string> &results)
{
   results.clear();
   results.resize(input.size());
    vector<thread> th;

    th.resize(input.size());


    for(int i=0; i<input.size();i++)
    {
        th[i]=thread(fold, input,ref(results), i );
    }

    for(auto & t : th)
    {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

The `fold` function copies a string, derived from the entry `i` of `input`, to the entry i of the `output`. I want to make sure when my_function  returns all the threads are terminated. The reason I ask this question is that after parallelizing this function I get huge memory leaks and am suspecting the threads keep the resources the take.

Comment: Yes all thread functions must have returned for the `join` calls to return. And all `join` calls must return before your `my_function` returns. All resources associated with the `std::thread` object will be released wither with the corresponding `join` call or when the object is destructed (which is done as part of returning from `my_function`). ***However*** if the thread function explicitly allocates resources that it doesn't release, then those won't be automatically cleaned up.

Comment: @Reza also you should protect `results` from parallel access. To avoid this problem, you should perform resize for results also, and each thread should know it's number, so it will modify just variable allocated for it, assuming each thread produce one result string

Comment: MCVE, please. What does fold do?

Answer (score 0):

Your function looks ill suited to parallelization. You are giving each thread a reference wrapper to the same vector that has been initially cleared. If the function `fold` resizes/reallocates `results` at all, then one thread will reallocate the data and work in the newly allocated space while other threads are trying to access the old, deleted space. Another possibility is multiple threads trying to resize the vector at the same time, causing multiple reallocations and leaks.

In general, letting multiple threads freely change the same data at the same time is a *very* bad idea, as you cannot know what will happen. Letting threads each change their own element in the vector without reordering, adding, or removing elements is fine. But at that point you should give the threads references to the individual strings they modify, not the vector containing them.

Comment: Corrected it, sorry.